# Bind LDAP connection to SASL auth using python-ldap

Tags: python, ldap, sasl, python-ldap

How can I bind an LDAP connection using SASL auth using the python-ldap module?

Should I configure anything specific on the Windows AD DC side as well?

Here's my code which raises an InvalidCredentials error

```py
import ldap
import ldap.sasl

HOST = "<IP>"
PORT = 636
user_name = "<AD user name>"
pwd = "<AD account password>"

PORT = 389
ldap_conn = ldap.initialize("ldap://[%s]:%s" % (HOST, PORT))

auth_tokens = ldap.sasl.digest_md5(user_name, pwd)
try:
    ldap_conn.sasl_interactive_bind_s("", auth_tokens)
    print(ldap_conn.whoami_s())
except ldap.INVALID_CREDENTIALS as e:
    print(e)
```

Running the code I get the result (The credentials are **correct** yet):

```
{'desc': 'Invalid credentials', 'info': '8009030C: LdapErr: DSID-0C09056D, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v2580'}
```

**Extra note:**
Running the search `ldapsearch -h <IP> -p 389 -x -b "" -s base -LLL supportedSASLMechanisms` in my PC returns:

```
dn:
supportedSASLMechanisms: GSSAPI
supportedSASLMechanisms: GSS-SPNEGO
supportedSASLMechanisms: EXTERNAL
supportedSASLMechanisms: DIGEST-MD5
```